# Algorithm to find all points on an Elliptic Curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, cryptography

i'm trying to find an algorithm that finds all points on an (projective) elliptic curve.

I find it hard to write an efficient algorithm that ignores points that are "Related".

For example, given the following (Projective) elliptic curve (a=b=1):

$${C = Y^2Z = X^3 + XZ^2 + Z^3}$$

under ${\mathbb{F}_3}$, the algorithm should return:

$${C(\mathbb{F}_3) = {(1:0:1),(0:1:2),(0:1:1),(0:1:0)}}$$
while ignoring:

$${(0:2:0),(0:2:1),(0:2:2),(2:0:2)}$$

One way to do so is to go over all options, but then when p is a large number (say >200), it takes way too long and impractical.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you have any preference, which of several related points to return? It seems you do so by postulating that the first non-zero component is $1$?

Comment: Also, do you know how to exploit the group law on $C$?

Comment: If your curves are given in Weierstrass form, then $(0:1:0)$ is the only point where $Z=0$. So you may as well just always write down that point, set $Z = 1$ in your equation, and look for points on the affine elliptic curve. This will eliminate the redundancy problem due to scaling. After that, it suffices to loop over all possible values for $x$, of which there are $p$, and check if the righthand side is a square. There might be some further shortcuts using quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: If you want something very efficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm

Comment: Do you want to list of the elements?